# Separating a list of strings into columns

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.6

```
import textwrap  

def get_coord(x,matrix):

    code = 'ADFGVX'  
    for i in range(len(matrix)):  
        for a in range(len(matrix[i])):  
            if matrix[i][a] == x:  
                return code[i] + code[a]  
    return -1, -1  

def encode(message, secret_alphabet, keyword):

    message = ''.join(message.split()).lower()   
    matrix = [secret_alphabet[i * 6:(i+1) * 6] for i in range(6)]  
    first = ''  
    lk = len(keyword)  
    for i in message:  
        first += get_coord(i, matrix)  
    first = textwrap.wrap(first, lk)    

encode("I am going", 
       "dhxmu4p3j6aoibzv9w1n70qkfslyc8tr5e2g",
       "cipher")
```

I have a list of strings that I need to zip together to create columns. I used `textwrap` to create this list:

after texwrapping first I get:

```
['FADVAG', 'XXDXFA', 'GDXX']
```

I need my output to look like:

```
['FXG', 'AXD', 'DDX', 'VXX', 'AF', 'GX']
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to include some of the code and how you got to the first array.

Comment: `'DDD'` is a typo it should be `'DDX'`

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `itertools.zip_longest` and `str.join`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [''.join(item) for item in zip_longest('FADVAG', 'XXDXFA', 'GDXX', fillvalue='')]
['FXG', 'AXD', 'DDX', 'VXX', 'AF', 'GA']
```

However, this doesn't produce your wanted third and last item. Was that a mistake in the original post?

Comment: Don't know why `'GA'` disappears in required list :). And strangely `'AX'` appears from somewhere.

Comment: sorry about my bad typing i had been at it for hours haha i will give this a shot though thanks

Comment: is there any way i can pass a list to zip_longest ans get the desired output?

Comment: @ChaseEllis You could use unpacking `zip_longest(*your_list, fillvalue='')` (note the leading `*` which unpacks the list).